# Accesskeys for enterprise web apps / SaaS - worth it?

Tags: web-app, accessibility, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

(Not sure what accesskeys are? [Here is an ALA post about them](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/accesskeys/))

If you've ever implemented accesskeys on a web app, do you know if they got used (outside of accessibility concerns)? There seem to be very few sites that use the ALT+[key] pattern and publicize them to users, so it doesn't seem to have caught on. I can't find any utilisation statistics.

My sample scenario is: you have a web app that a busy professional might use for 1-2 hours a day, filling in forms. They are going to become intermediate / power users fairly quickly. Accesskeys may speed up their flow for certain tasks. We'd point out which buttons/functions have an accesskey through styling (underlining the first letter, etc), and through help & FAQs. 
Given this scenario, do you think users would use the accesskeys, or is it just too unusual / unnatural for them?

They are easy enough to implement, but are there any reasons NOT to allow accesskeys?

PS I know [Twitter](http://lifehacker.com/5638189/navigate-the-new-twitter-with-like-a-pro-with-keyboard-shortcuts) and Google have advanced accesskey support, but again - I don't know if it gets used, even by power users.

Answer (score 1):

This [WebAIM article on keyboard accessibility](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey) discusses accesskeys. In summary, some of the issues with accesskeys include:

- Shortcuts are not all the same, or in some cases even similar, across browsers
- Hard to show users accesskeys are available
- Users' own prefs, browser, or assistive technology might conflict with your accesskeys
- No standard set of accesskeys, though there are some recommendations

A further article, [Using Accesskeys - Is it worth it?](http://www.wats.ca/show.php?contentid=32), discusses the practicality of accesskeys, addressing accessibility concerns in particular:

> Disappointingly, our research discovered that all but 3 keys were previously "claimed" by one technology or the other...
>
> implementation brings with it the possibility that it either will not be available to all users, or that the keystroke combination encoded within the web page may conflict with a reserved keystroke combination in an adaptive technology or future user agent.

I have considered implementing accesskeys, but never have, as I've always had more pressing usability and accessibility issues to work on.